# the attribute name "Name" on this element is not defined in the DTD/Schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

I am getting the above error while i do a xslt transform to a XML using a schema ...any idea what the error could be ?[image]

Comment: That's a poorly defined question. You could at least post error as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the `EnterpriseDocument` element has no `Name` attribute defined in the schema.

It would help us if you could transcribe the dialog message to text so that - for example - it can be read into code. It's hard to expect SO readers to work with such tiny non-character material